# compute pointwise limit and show convergence is uniform

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

here's my question. 
I really don't understand this section so if someone could talk me through this first one I'm hoping I might have a chance at the rest.
Cheers.

Let $f_k:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as

$f_k(x)= x \cdot \exp(-kx^2)$, for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Compute the pointwise limit $f$ of the sequence and show that the convergence is uniform.

Is the following equality satisfied:

$\lim_{k\to \infty} f'_k(0)=f'(0)$

Comment: I find it hard to believe you can't find the pointwise limit. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the functions $f_k $ are odd.

$$k>0 \implies f_k (0)=0 $$
$$\implies \lim_{k\to+\infty}f_k (0)=0$$

For $x\ne 0 , \lim_{k\to+\infty}xe^{-kx^2}=0$

because the exponential is faster.
$$(\lim_{X\to+\infty}Xe^{-X}=0)$$

there is a pointwise convergence to zero function at $[0,1] $.

$$f_k' (x)=(1-2kx^2)e^{-kx^2}$$

$f_k'(x)=0 $ gives $x=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2k}} $

$$\max_{[0,1]}\{|f_k (x)|\}=\frac {1}{\sqrt {2k}}e^{-\frac 12} $$
which goes to zero.

the convergence is uniform at $[-1,1] $.

$f_k'(0)=1$.